# How to get title, description from html agility?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I want to get title, description from web. I use

```
var title= (from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
     "//div[@class='section sectionMain recentNews']//a[@class='newsTitle']")
     select item).ToList();

var des= (from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
     "//div[@class='section sectionMain recentNews']//div[@class='newsText']") 
     select item).ToList();
```

Now, i want to use a query select all title, description like:

```
var data = (from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
"//div[@class='section sectionMain recentNews']") select new 
{
    title =..........., description =.......
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way which you can use is to combine both lists if you don't want to do it in a same loop:

```
 var title= (from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
 "//div[@class='section sectionMain recentNews']//a[@class='newsTitle']")
 select item).ToList();

var des= (from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
     "//div[@class='section sectionMain recentNews']//div[@class='newsText']") 
     select item).ToList();

var items = title.Zip(des, (t, d) => new {Title = t, Description = v })
```

Hope this helps :)